# Acceder a objetos creados por vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs, vuetify

Tengo un array llamado `filteredData`, este array se lo paso a una `b-table` de `vuetify` y ella la muestra en una tabla, al ser una tabla filtrable, el los datos cambian su orden, pero no lo hacen en el array `filteredData`, por lo que vi con **vue devtools**, se creo un objeto temporal que se llama `newData`, hay manera de que yo acceda a el?

[image: array filteredData]

[image: array newData]

[image: asi fue declarado el prop de vuetify]

Comment: Puedes tomar una captura del vue devtools para ver donde lo creó

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto

Answer (score 0):

Solucione, al ser un objeto del DOM se creo en el objeto ref.

Lo encontre de esta forma: `this.$refs.{{nombre-del-componente}}.newData`